# C# Lambda Expression translated strange, Any Suggestions?

Tags: c#, lambda, dapper

I have problem with the following lambda expression:

```
public IEnumerable<ModuleEntity> GetPageList(Pagination pagi, string query)
{
    var expression = LinqExpression.Default<ModuleEntity>();
    expression = expression.And(e =>
       e.DeleteMark != 1 &&
       e.EnableMark != 0
    );

   return this.BaseRepository().GetList(expression, pagi);
}
```

This is my code, I want to add default expression to my business.
Note: the properties `EnableMark` and `DeleteMark` are `nullable<int>`.
When I debug, the lambda expression translate the expression to this:

```
{p => ((1 == 1) AndAlso ((p.DeleteMark != Convert(1)) AndAlso (p.EnableMark != Convert(0))))};
```

It leads to my Query throwing an exception:

```
// use Dapper connection Query
var query = dbConnection.Query<T>(linq);
```

> Exception: Unrecognized NodeType (Convert),

I can't  figure out why the lambda expression gives me `Covnert(1)` and `Convert(0)`, any suggestions?

---

I tried to change the property `EnableMark` and `DeleteMark` to `int` instead of `nullable<int>`, then it worked. But in the other cases, `nullable type` is necessary, is there any solutions or documents ?
Thanks.

---

@Eric Lippert Thank you for pointing out the causes, I set a variable of value '1', let it's type to `int?`, and assigned to DeleteMark. It worked !!

```
public IEnumerable<ModuleEntity> GetPageList(Pagination pagi, string query)
{
    var expression = LinqExpression.Default<ModuleEntity>();
    int? deleteMark = 1;
    int? enableMark = 0
    expression = expression.And(e =>
       e.DeleteMark != deleteMark &&
       e.EnableMark != enableMark
    );

   return this.BaseRepository().GetList(expression, pagi);
}
```

Comment: Is `var param = query.ToJObject()` related to the question? If not, could you delete them?

Comment: Please uncomment or remove any code that shouldn't be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure out why the lambda expression gives me Convert(1) and Convert(0)

As you note, the DeleteMark and EnableMark are nullable ints. C# does not define a comparison operator between ints and nullable ints.  It does define a comparison operator between two nullable ints, and a conversion from int to nullable int. The lambda conversion captures the fact that the integers 1 and 0 have been converted to nullable integers in order to do the comparison.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how to improve it, nullable type is necessary in many cases, can't it be converted directly before translating ?